# Bash/Linux if elif else issue

Tags: linux, bash

Currently working on my bash skills. I've done a few activites based on if/elif/else given to me to my tutor but can't put my finger on the one below.

Basically I'm tasked with outputting the following based on the input of a grade.
 Less than 40% = Fail 40% to 59% = Pass 60% to 69% = Merit 70% and above = Distinction

It seems to get caught on the first elif, presents the grade as merit for anything below 70 and doesn't check the others, it gives the same result when I change the order too.

```
echo "Please enter your grade"
read GRADE
echo

     if [ $GRADE -ge 70 ]; then
         echo "Well done, you got a distinction"

    elif [ $GRADE -ge 60 ] || [ $GRADE -le 69 ]; then
          echo "Well done, you got a merit"
    elif [ $GRADE -ge 40 ] || [ $GRADE -le 59 ]; then
          echo "Well done, you got a pass"
    else 
          echo "Unfortunately you failed"
      fi
```

Comment: Your statement uses `||` (logical OR), rather than `&&` (logical AND).

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be a basic syntax error and needed fresh eyes!

Comment: In fact, you can omit the `[ $GRADE -le ... ]` completely. The order of the the `elif`s already ensures that the grade is less than `...`.

Comment: Pretty much any number is either `>= 60` or `<=69`. You have a logical error there.

Answer (score 1):

A bit unusual solution

```
#bash 4.0+
while read -r -p 'Grade? (h-help)> ' grade
do
    case "$grade" in
        q) echo "quitting..." ; exit 0 ;;
        h) echo "Enter numeric value (0..100) or q for quit" ;&
        '') continue ;;
        *[!0-9]*) echo "Must be numeric value" ; continue ;;
    esac
    case 1 in
        $((grade > 100)) ) echo "impossible" ;;
        $((grade >= 70)) ) echo "distinction" ;;
        $((grade >= 60)) ) echo "merit" ;;
        $((grade >= 40)) ) echo "pass" ;;
                        *) echo "fail" ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in using `||` (or) rather than `&&` (and).
If you put in "10", 10 is LESS THAN 69 so it will drop into the first `else`.

Using `set -x` at the top of your script will help you figure this sort of thing out.

Answer (score 0):

There better to use `-a` for AND and `-o` for OR in `[]`. And do something like this:

```
if   [ $GRADE -lt 40 ]; then
    echo "Unfortunately you failed"
elif [ $GRADE -ge 40 -a $GRADE -lt 60 ]; then
    echo "Well done, you got a pass"
elif [ $GRADE -ge 60 -a $GRADE -lt 70 ]; then
    echo "Well done, you got a merit"
else
    echo "Well done, you got a distinction"
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem came from the || (or), you need to use && (and). For exemple 65 is greater than 60 AND lesser than 69.

```
echo "Please enter your grade"
read GRADE
echo

 if [ $GRADE -ge 70 ]; then
     echo "Well done, you got a distinction"

elif [ $GRADE -ge 60 ] && [ $GRADE -le 69 ]; then
      echo "Well done, you got a merit"
elif [ $GRADE -ge 40 ] && [ $GRADE -le 59 ]; then
      echo "Well done, you got a pass"
else
      echo "Unfortunately you failed"
  fi
```

Comment: Lots of bugs still present than this. If the user enters `-e . -o 1` as their grade, then they'll be told they got a distinction with no error, because the `test` invocations will look at whether `.` exists before they do any numeric comparisons at all. Quoting will cause such cases to (correctly) result in a failure with an error: `if [ "$GRADE" -ge 70 ]`

Comment: Moreover, all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; names with at least one lowercase character are guaranteed not to conflict with names meaningful to POSIX-specified tools. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.